# how to make video player fluid width and height?

Tags: jquery

how would you make these video players height and width 100% and resize with the page
http://scripts.reloadlab.net/customYtPlayer/

`<a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD2LRROpph0" style="width: 100%;"></a>`

makes the video player the width of the window and it remains that way when resizing it whereas i want it to be resizable with the window. and you cant specify height but i would also like that to be resizeable with the window when resizing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate question can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/27294107/4000669

Comment: @ShahrukhAzeem There's a difference between JavaScript and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use fitvids.js, a responsive jQuery plugin for fluid width video 
http://fitvidsjs.com/

Comment: Works only for width.