# Fluid Silverlight Video Player With Calc (100vw / 1.7777778)

Tags: css, silverlight, cross-browser

I have a [Silverlight video player](http://test.flcbranson.org/flcevents.php).  When the width of the page is less than 960px, the player goes to 100% width.  I'm trying to get the height to adjust along with the width (width / 1.77777778 + 40px for the controls).

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) states that `calc()` is supported in IE9+, Firefox 14+, Chrome 21+, and Safari 6+.  [It](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) also states that `vw` is supported in IE9+, Chrome 21+, and Safari 6+ (no Firefox).

I am using this bit of HTML:

```
<!-- I put silverlight first because firefox and opera won't embed an mp4/mp3
    firefox won't fall back to the silverlight install link if only mp4/mp3 is available (webm or ogg must be available for the fallback to work) -->
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2">
    <!-- load the player -->
    <param name="source" value="http://iissmooth.webcastcenter.com/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"/>
    <!-- note the DeliveryMethod -->
    <param name="InitParams" value="DeliveryMethod=Progressive Download, mediaurl=http://www.flcbranson.org/media/GreaterFaithConference2013-Ad.mp4" />
        <!-- silverlight install link -->
        <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0"><img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"></a></p>
        <p><a href="media/GreaterFaithConference2013-Ad.mp4">Download Video (MP4)</a></p>
</object>
```

And this bit of CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:959px) {
    .events object {
        height:-moz-calc(100vw / 1.777777778 + 40px);
        height:-webkit-calc(100vw / 1.777777778 + 40px);
        height:-ms-calc(100vw / 1.777777778 + 40px);
        height:-o-calc(100vw / 1.777777778 + 40px);
        height:calc(100vw / 1.777777778 + 40px);
    }
}
```

In theory, it should work in IE9+ and Chrome 21+ (both support `calc()` and `vw`.  Unfortunately, only IE9+ works (I was quite impressed with the level of `calc()` support that IE has).

I have yet to see a tutorial or example of combining `calc()`, `vw`, and division for fluid heights, so maybe the combination is the issue.

Is there something wrong in my code, or should this be working (maybe I found a bug)?

To dissuade suggestions, I have tried JQuery's `height()` already (it isn't fluid since you have to refresh for each change to go into effect).  I guess I could include a function to watch the width of the page all the time.  My effort is to do it with CSS, though.

I did see, [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014731/how-to-make-video-player-fluid-width-and-height), reference to [FitVid.JS](http://fitvidsjs.com/).  There is reference to Vimeo, YouTube, etc..., but I question whether it would work with a local Silverlight player (I require Silverlight for many, many, WMVs).

Answer (score 0):

Height calculation can be done entirely in css using relative padding. This technique is used by Foundation Framework for their Flex Video. For detailed explanation please check http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Comment: Hehehe...  I am doing that in another area, but not with the video player in question (`#content { padding-top:56.24%; }`).  That's for a 100% width banner graphic that gets taller or shorter with the width of the page.